# I can't see my spotlight in the final render, I'm new to this, btw

Tags: rendering, light, 2d

Basically I'm starting out in Blender, doing some bouncing ball in 2D and a moving 3D cube, nothing fancy. In the final render I can't figure out why in the world I can't see the light source, could it be because of my hardware? (Macbook pro mid 2014, 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7, 16gb ram, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB). I've tried for render engines Eevee, cycles and workbench, but none appear to work, although an object with emission is visible. I'll post some pictures of blender and the renders.

[image]. [image]

Comment: show us your blend file

Comment: https://we.tl/t-x0h0yxsJGS I have no ideea if I can just post it onto the form itself. Is a wetransfer link ok? Thanks!

Comment: it works, but normally you should use https://blend-exchange.com/ ... ;) just follow the instructions. for now this is ok. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made nearly everything right, just change the render engine to Cycles and then you get:

[image]

and by the way: i rendered it on a macbook too...so it just works ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris!

Comment: you are welcome. it would be nice if you could check my answer as "correct" ;)

Comment: Hopefully I did it this time. The checkmarker on the left, right?

Comment: yes, perfect! Thank you!